# BufferedImage How do I stop all the images from having the color from the last one painted

Tags: java, bufferedimage, paintcomponent, ppm

I'm using Java, and I'm reading from a ppm file, code P3.

```
P3
# The P3 means colors are in ASCII, then 3 columns and 2 rows,
# then 255 for max color, then RGB triplets
3 2
255
255   0   0     0 255   0     0   0 255
255 255   0   255 255 255     0   0   0
```

My objective with this file is to paint 6 images with the rgb values above, however all the images always stay the same color as the last rgb values. Here's my code:

```
public class Window2 extends JFrame {

    public JMenuBar menubar;
    public JMenuItem importFile;
    public Scanner filePath;
    StringTokenizer tokens = null;
    ArrayList<BufferedImage> image = new ArrayList<>();
    int[][][] images;
    JPanel panelDown = new JPanel();
    MyPanel myPanel;
    Color myColor;

    int[] coords = new int[2];
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            for (BufferedImage image1 : image) {
                g.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, null);
            }

        }
    }

    public Window2() {
        super("Exercise 2");
        menubar = new JMenuBar();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panelBar = new JPanel();
        add(panelBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panelDown, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        importFile = new JMenuItem("Import", 'I');
        panelBar.add(menubar);
        menubar.add(importFile);
        importFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(Window2.this, "Import Maze", FileDialog.LOAD);
                fd.setFile(".txt");
                fd.setLocation(Window2.this.getX() + 100, Window2.this.getY() + 100);
                fd.show();
                if (!fd.getFile().endsWith(".txt")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Window2.this, "Wrong file extension", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    File theFile = new File(fd.getDirectory() + "\\" + fd.getFile());
                    try {
                        filePath = new Scanner(theFile);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Window2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    images = readFile(filePath);
                    panelDown.setLayout(new GridLayout(coords[0], coords[1]));
                    int z=0;
                    for (int k = 0; k < coords[0]; k++) {
                        for (int l = 0; l < coords[1]; l++) {
                            int red = images[k][l][0];
                            int green = images[k][l][1];
                            int blue = images[k][l][2];
                            myPanel = new MyPanel();
                            panelDown.add(myPanel);
                            image.add(new BufferedImage(30, 30, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
                            myColor = new Color(red,green,blue,255);
                            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                                for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
                                    image.get(z).setRGB(i, j, myColor.getRGB());  
                                }
                            }
                            z++;
                        }
                    }
                    myPanel.repaint();
                }
            }
        });

        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

There is one method missing here, it's the readFile. It returns an array[][][], number of rows, columns and the rgb values respectifully. Any ideia on how I can fix this?

Comment: And the color values for each image are what you are expecting?

Comment: Also, the images are painting over each other in your `paintComponent` method...

Comment: the images should be, red, green, blue, yellow, white, black, but all six images appear black. If they are painting over each other, how can I see 6 different images?

Comment: You're seeing the same image 6 times, because your `paintComponent` method is painting all the images at the same location within the context of each instance of `MyPanel`.  Try only painting 1, probably by passing `z` to `MyPanel` so it knows which image to paint...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyPanel` is painting ALL the images every time it is painted, so each instance of `MyPanel` is showing the LAST image which was added to the `images` `List`...

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        for (BufferedImage image1 : image) {
            g.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, null);
        }

    }
}
```

You then create and add an instance of `MyPanel` for each image...

```
myPanel = new MyPanel();
panelDown.add(myPanel);
```

But, `MyPanel` is painting ALL the image on top of each other, so only the last image added to the `List` is displayed...

Instead, try passing the individual image to be painted to `MyPanel`

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferdImage img;

    public MyPanel(BufferdImage img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

And then when you build the image, pass a reference to the `MyPanel` instance, for example.

```
for (int k = 0; k < coords[0]; k++) {
    for (int l = 0; l < coords[1]; l++) {
        //...
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(30, 30, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        image.add(img);
        myColor = new Color(red,green,blue,255);
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
                image.get(z).setRGB(i, j, myColor.getRGB());  
            }
        }
        myPanel = new MyPanel(img);
        panelDown.add(myPanel);
        z++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn, I never would've remembered to use a constructor in `MyPanel` --' Looks like I still have looong way to go. Thanks alot :D